# How do I combine lenses and functors?

Tags: haskell, lenses, haskell-lens

I'm trying to get used to the `lens` library for Haskell, and find myself struggling at some simple problems. For instance, let's say (for convenience) that `at` and `_1` have the following types (this is how I understand them, at least):

```
at :: Ord k => k -> Lens' (Map k v) (Maybe v)

_1 :: Lens' (a, b) a
```

How do I combine these lenses into a lens with the following type:

```
maybeFst :: Ord k => k -> Lens' (Map k (a, b)) (Maybe a)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd like a lens like

```
Lens' (Maybe (a, b)) (Maybe a)
```

but that can't quite be a `Lens` since putting back `Nothing` affects the `b` as well. It can be a `Getter`

```
getA :: Getter (Maybe (a, b)) (Maybe a)
getA = to (fmap fst)
```

but then when you compose it you'll just wind up with a `Getter` as well, not a full `Lens`

```
maybeFst :: Ord k => k -> Getter (Map k (a, b)) (Maybe a)
maybeFst k = at k . getA
```

Probably better than that is to use a `Traversal` instead

```
maybeFstT :: Ord k => k -> Traversal' (Map k (a, b)) a
maybeFstT k = at k . _Just . _1
```

This will allow you to both get (using `preview` or `toListOf`) and set values at the `fst` of the values in your map, but you won't be able to modify its existence in the map: if the value does not exist you cannot add it and if it does exist you cannot remove it.

---

Finally, we can jury-rig a fake `Lens` which has the appropriate type, though we have to give it a default value for `b`

```
getA :: b -> Lens' (Maybe (a, b)) (Maybe a)
getA b inj Nothing       = (\x -> (,b) <$> x) <$> inj Nothing
getA _ inj (Just (a, b)) = (\x -> (,b) <$> x) <$> inj (Just a)
```

but notice that it has some not-very-`Lens`like behavior.

```
>>> Just (1, 2) & getA 0 .~ Nothing & preview (_Just . _2)
Nothing

>>> Nothing & getA 0 .~ Just 1
Just (1,0)
```

so often it's better to avoid these pseudolenses to prevent mishaps.

Comment: Thank you, I see now how the type I was asking for could never be a lens! :)

Comment: As a final note, if we had an `Iso' (a, b) a` (which obviously is impossible, then we could use `mapping ourIso :: Iso' (Maybe (a, b)) (Maybe a)` in place of `getA`. To wit, try `fl (a, b) = (b, a)` with `flipP = iso fl fl` and then `maybeFlip k = at k . mapping flipP :: Ord k => k -> Lens' (Map k (a, b)) (Maybe (b, a))`.

Comment: Just a small clarification: The reason that your first example can't be a lens is that you can't invent a `b` to put in when having `Nothing` and trying to put in `Just a`. The inverse case works just fine. Here is my attempt: `impossible :: Lens' (Maybe (a,b)) (Maybe a);`
`impossible k (Just (a,b)) = fmap (,b) <$> k (Just a);`
`impossible k Nothing = fmap (,undefined) <$> k Nothing`. I first wrote `impossible k Nothing = Nothing <$ k Nothing`, but that doesn't fulfill the lens laws.